# how to convert csharp 8 code to earlier version

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-8.0

I need to change this code to work on early versions of c#
In the following code how to change condition like this one

```cs
if (value is TimeSpan ts)
```

to ealier c# ?

```cs
string parsedValue;
bool parsed;

if (value == DateTime d && d >= BaseDate)
{
    parsedValue = d.ToOADate().ToInvariantString();
    parsed = true;
    SetDateTimeFormat(style, d.Date == d);
}
else if (value is TimeSpan ts)
{
    parsedValue = ts.TotalDays.ToInvariantString();
    parsed = true;
    SetTimeSpanFormat(style);
}
else if (value is Boolean b)
{
    parsedValue = b ? "1" : "0";
    _dataType = XLDataType.Boolean;
    parsed = true;
}
```

Also in the following code

```cs
private static Boolean TryGetBasicValue<T, U>(String currentValue, ParseFunction<U> parseFunction, out T value)
{
    if (parseFunction.Invoke(currentValue, NumberStyles.Any, null, out U result))
    {
        value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T).GetUnderlyingType());
        return true;
    }

    value = default;
    return false;
}
```

how to change c# 7

```cs
value = default;
```

to earlier c# code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `value is TimeSpan ts` checks the runtime type of `value` and copies that value into the `ts` variable if its type is `TimeSpan`. Value types that are boxed, will be unboxed as part of the copying.

Note that `System.TimeSpan`, presumably the type you're dealing with here, is a value type, and so is *not* compatible with the `as` operator, which is required to return a reference type (so that it can return `null` when the type isn't correct).

So in your example, you'll need to check the type and then unbox the value explicitly, like so:

```cs
...
else if (value is TimeSpan)
{
    TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)value;

    parsedValue = ts.TotalDays.ToInvariantString();
    parsed = true;
    SetTimeSpanFormat(style);
}
...
```

The second one is easier, as `default` can just be replaced by `default(T)`. E.g. `value = default(T);`.

Answer (score 1):

#### C# 7: is operator pattern or Is-expression with pattern

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern)

```cs
if (value is TimeSpan ts)
```

#### C# 3: is and as operators

[Reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)

```cs
TimeSpan? ts = value as TimeSpan?;
if (ts.HasValue) 
   ...
```

or

```cs
if (value is TimeSpan) 
   TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)value;
```

---

#### C# 7: default literal

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal)

```cs
value = default;
```

#### C# 3: default operator

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-operator)

```cs
value = default(T);
```

Comment: The above use of `as` does not work with value types, and `TimeSpan` is a value type. Additionally, if you _are_ going to use `as`, it makes more sense to just _start_ with `as`, and compare the result to `null` for the type check, e.g. `MyReferenceType mrt = value as MyReferenceType; if (mrt != null) { ... }`

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are right, I was not paying attention to the type itself. I've updated my post.

Comment: Well, except now you've proposed using `TimeSpan?` which is useless in the OP's case because they will still need to either cast to `TimeSpan` to access the struct's members, or they'll have to use `ts.Value` instead. And as I mentioned before, if you're going to use the `as` operator, it's pointless to start with `is`; just start with `as` and check the result for `null`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That alternative is also included in the post.

Comment: The problem I described was present at the time I wrote the comment. Looks like you took advantage of the editing grace period to modify the post without generating a new edit record in the revisions. I still dispute the utility of using `TimeSpan?` as it does nothing other than add overhead and an extra line of code. But at least there's nothing technically _wrong_ in your post now.